# Recoursive factories with FactoryGirls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'm looking for a comfortable way to create a recoursive factory.
In my app User has many Software and I'd like to create "in one shot" an user with n related software.
This is my code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do |f|
     f.sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}" }
 end

 trait :with_software do
    ignore do
         n 3
    end

 after :create do |user, evaluator|
     FactoryGirl.create_list :software, evaluator.n, :user => user
 end
```

while software is defined as below

```
 factory :software do |f|
     f.sequence(:name) { |n| "software#{n}" }
     f.association :user
 end
```

when I digit:

```
user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :with_software)
```

FactoryGirls creates an user with 3 related software entries. The problem is that the software names are always "software#{n}".
How can I specify an unique software name as :user.name + "software#{n}" ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you are talking about is not recursive, but that's not important.

You could achieve what you want by the following:

```
 factory :software do |f|
     f.sequence(:name) { |n| "software#{n}" }
     f.association :user

     trait :with_matching_name do
       f.name { "#{f.user.name}#{f.name}" }
     end
 end

 factory :user do |f|
     f.sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}" }

     trait :with_software do
       ignore do
           n 3
       end
     end

     after :create do |user, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list :software, evaluator.n, :user => user, :with_matching_name
     end
  end
```

You can try, if it works.

Comment: I receive from the create_list the following error: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC.  it driving me crazy

Comment: It seems that it does not like the end of line in create_list and would like to see "=>". You can also try what happens when you don't use create_list but n.times and then FactoryGirl.create..

Comment: Same error: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError). The error is related to :with_matching_name option ., P.S. Thanks for your evaluable help

Comment: You can also try to set the name of the software in the after create loop inside the trait and then save the software. Maybe it has some problems with that.